# Azure Appservice to Appservice networking error 403

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have my UI (react) in one subscription and the backend on the different subscription in app service. I am trying to run the UI but while communicating with backend I am getting 403 Forbidden error.

I have added UI URL to cors origin allowed in backend app service.

Comment: 403 is not CORS, but means the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it

Comment: Is the 403 error on the client side (i.e. in your web browser) or server-side (i.e. within the app service)?

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Thiago’s response. Based on your description (if I have understood you correctly), those are two different apps, and this scenario is a case of multitier apps.

**Short Answer:**
You may use VNet Integration to connect your front-end web app to a subnet in a virtual network. Doing so will enable your web app to make calls into your virtual network. After your front-end app is connected to the virtual network, you can decide how to lock down access to your backend application.

**Long Answer:**
By default, apps hosted in App Service are accessible directly through the internet and can reach only internet-hosted endpoints.

You can control network/IP access Access restrictions, VNET with NSG, Service endpoints and Private endpoints and etc.
Please check this '[App Service networking features](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking-features)' doc for networking features in App Service and leverage the combination of the features as per your requirement.

**Additional info**:

Error 403 -Typically, the web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access.
You may use the F12 tools in the browser and inspect the network traffic it will perhaps say:  Status Code: 403 Ip Forbidden

All Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available.

[Azure WebApps Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#networking-restrictionsconsiderations)